# Is there a way to edit the values of a tibble that you've scraped?

Tags: r, tibble

I scraped river flow data from a USGS website and the flow data is accompanied by the letters A, P, or E to show actual, predicted, or estimated flows. Is there a way to truncate the data so that it doesn't show the A, P, and/or E's?

```
flows_raw <- "https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ut/nwis/dv?cb_00060=on&format=html&site_no=10163000&referred_module=sw&period=&begin_date=2010-10-14&end_date=2020-10-14" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[2] %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  as_tibble()
flows_raw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself but if someone has a cleaner method I'd still love to see it.

```
   flows_raw <- "https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ut/nwis/dv?cb_00060=on&format=html&site_no=10163000&referred_module=sw&period=&begin_date=2008-11-14&end_date=2020-10-14" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[2] %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%

  # remove extraneous info from the values marked by the letters A, P, or E

  separate(`Dis-charge, ft3/s,(Mean)`, into = c("edit1", "extra"), convert = TRUE, sep = "A") %>% 
  separate(edit1, into = c("edit2", "extra"), convert = TRUE, sep = "P") %>% 
  separate(edit2, into = c("Cubic Ft/Sec (mean)", "extra"), convert = TRUE, sep = "E") %>% 

  # delete the column that we moved the A, P, and E's into
  
  select(-extra) %>%
  as_tibble()
```